# Changing element size on mouseover using D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've made a stacked bar chart in the past and I've added some neat effects on mouseover. Adding onto these I'd like to change the size of the rectangle that my user is hovering on, and return to the default size once the mouse leaves the rectangle.

The goal is to make the rectangle change in size on mouseover, therefore I started with the height by using:

```
        .on('mouseover', function(d){
        d3.select(this).style("height", "110%");
      } )
```

Expecting the rectangle to receive a height of 110% compared to it's original height. Sadly it doesn't work this way, instead it gets 110% of the `div`'s height. So I tried using a D3 selector instead:

```
        .on('mouseover', function(d){
        d3.select(this).style("height", d3.select(this).style("height")*1.10));
      } )
```

But this didn't solve the issue either, with this code there's no change in size. If I log the height of the element I'm creating my log reads `auto` which leads me to believe I'm doing something wrong in obtaining the height value of the `rect`, what syntax should I be using?

EDIT: Trying echonax's answer below, the full code of the `rect` element in my stacked bar chart is as follows:

```
 Jaar.selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); })
    .style("opacity", 1)
    .on('mouseover', function(d){
        d.color = color(d.name);
        d3.select(this).style("opacity", 1);
        d3.select(this).style("height", height*1.1);
        d3.select(this).style("width", width*1.1);
        console.log(d3.select(this).style("width"));
        tip.show(d);
      } )
      .on('mouseout', function(d) {
        d3.select(this).style("opacity", 0.6);
        d3.select(this).style("height", height);
        d3.select(this).style("width", width);
        tip.hide(d);
      } );
```

Comment: Can you give a little more detail about your selection(the element your `.on` function is binded to)?

Comment: The `.on` function is bound to `rect`, I've added the full code trying you solution below to the OP, sadly this does not give me the result I'm looking for. The elements just become huge.

Comment: As I understand it "height" is the height of the rect element, this is calculated based on the data. (as seen in the ` .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
d3.select(this).attr("height", (y(d.y0) - y(d.y1))*1.1);
```

to change the size to 110%

You can't do `d3.select(this).style("height")*1.10` because `d3.select(this).style("height")` is a String equal to "100px" for example.

What you can do is remove the "px" from the String, multiply by 1.1 and then add "px" to the end

```
var newHeight = parseInt(d3.select(this).style("height"))*1.1 + "px";
d3.select(this).style("height", newHeight);
```

Comment: This does the trick, although it's not as elegant as I was hoping for. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: It does! Sadly if I refer to the old height by Jaar.height it doesn't work, so I'm sticking with the less elegant solution for now to save some time. Do you have any idea on how to use the center of the 'rect' element as starting point for the size? The transition now expands the size only to the right and downward.

Comment: If you can create a fiddle with your code I can have a look

Comment: Plunkr can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/t84qcNuqjrGxT0RMFT4Y?p=preview). I just noticed that the height change isn't working either, I'm going to look into that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113603/discussion-between-tim-b-and-yoeri).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fiddle for demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/q5q6331p/16/

```
  .on("mouseover", function(d) { 
    d3.select(this).attr("height", function(d){
        return (y(d.y0) - y(d.y0 + d.y))*1.5
    });
  })
  .on("mouseout", function(d) { 
    d3.select(this).attr("height", function(d){
        return (y(d.y0) - y(d.y0 + d.y))
    });
  })
```

Comment: This solution changes the size of the `rect` element to 1.5 times the size of the `div` (or actually 1.5 time the size of the SVG, on second thought), similar to my first attempt in the OP.